# Question for PHP Time Calculator Based on Distance

Tags: php, forms

I'm working on a project where I have to calculate the hours and minutes a train ride will take based on distance (in miles/hour), stops taken (5 minutes added per stop), and weather (Good weather train speed is 50 mph, in bad weather it is 40 mph). I'm getting correct output when I run it with good weather but when I enter 50 miles, 2 stops, bad weather, I'm getting 1 hour and 20 minutes when I should get 1 hour and 25 minutes. Here is my full form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Passenger Train</title>
</head>
<header>
</header>
<body>
<h1>Passenger Train</h1>
<hr>
<p>Enter the distance and number of stops and specify if the weather  is good or bad.</p>
<form method="POST" action="PassengerTrain.php">
<input type="text" name="distance" /> Distance (in miles)<br />
<input type="text" name="stops" /> Number of Stops<br />
<input type="radio" name="weather" id="goodWeather" value="goodWeather">
<label for="goodWeather">Weather is Good</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="weather" id="badWeather" value="badWeather">
<label for="badWeather">Weather is Bad</label><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calc. Travel Time" />
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(is_numeric($_POST['distance']) && is_numeric($_POST['stops'])) {
        if($_POST['weather'] == "badWeather") {
            $speed = 40;
            }
        else {
            $speed = 50;
            }
        $distance = $_POST['distance'];
        $stops = $_POST['stops'];
        $hours = intval($distance / $speed);
        $minutes = $distance % $speed;
        $extraTime = $stops * 5;
        $minutes += $extraTime;
        if ($minutes > 60) {
            $minutes = $minutes - 60;
            $hours = $hours + 1;
            }
        echo "Based on the information given your trip will take " . $hours . " hours and " . 
$minutes . " minutes.";
    }
    else {
        echo "You must enter numeric values for distance and number of stops.";
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Where could I fix this issue or what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, the problem is that you are not working the minutes out as minutes.

To reduce the main calculation to 1 step, you can add the stops into the time taken by the speed and distance, dividing the total time for the stops (stops * 5) by 60 (to make it into a decimal representing parts of an hour).  Then split this into the hours and minutes without need for any further adjustments...

```
$time = $distance / $speed + ($stops * 5) / 60;
$hours = intval($time);
$minutes = ($time - $hours) * 60;
```

which with your values, will give...

```
Based on the information given your trip will take 1 hours and 25 minutes.
```

Answer (score 2):

This equation is incorrect:

```
$minutes = $distance % $speed;
```

Consider a few sample inputs:

```
50 / 40 = 1 remainder 10
60 / 40 = 1 remainder 20
70 / 40 = 1 remainder 30
80 / 40 = 2 remainder  0
```

Even clearer, imagine a speed of 70:

```
135 / 70 = 1 remainder 65
```

The remainder here doesn't represent minutes, which should range from 0 to 59. To get that you need to do something to change the divisor from the speed, to a fixed 60 minutes per hour, e.g.

```
$minutes = ($distance % $speed) / $speed * 60;
```

Or:

```
$minutes = (($distance / $speed) - $hours) * 60;
```

Or work in minutes and calculate the hours at the end:

```
$minutes = $distance / $speed * 60;
while ($minutes > 60) {
   $minutes = $minutes - 60;
   $hours = $hours + 1;
}
```

Or without the loop:

```
$hours = intdiv($minutes, 60);
$minutes -= ($hours * 60);
```

(I haven't tested these, so may have made a mistake; *caveat emptor*)

Comment: Nice, it's actually better than my idea. EDIT: Oh, I actually wrote the same as the last one, it's just formatted nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
$minutes = $distance % $speed;
```

In case of 50 distance with 40 speed the result will be 10, not 10 minutes. And then you add another 2*5 to the time in minute, giving the final result of 20.

Personally, I would use minutes to calculate the distance, and only change it to hours+minutes at the very end. Be careful, as 40/50 will give 1,25 hours, which is 1 hour 15 minutes, and then you add the remaining 10 minutes, tallying the final 1 hour 25 minutes.